# wind generator for electronic devices

Tags: generator

I'm trying to run a mini project about wind generator for charging electronic devices(smartphones, mp3 player, powerbank,  etc). Rough project description; I want to  have several usb ports and the supply is from wind generator.  Mostly electronic devices that    use 5V . So the questions are:

1. Type of suitable motor for wind generator(small in size because it's mini project)
2. Suitable current output
3. List of components that I need(please recommend)

Comment: what wind speed is avail and roof top generator size can you accept

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 i plan to get wind of fan in my room. Is it strong enough to rotate the blade?

Comment: not even  to power an LED

Comment: how "small in size" do you wish ? wind vs blade need space. don't you think of it ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCGVOdRoDPg .. the size just like in the video. try watching it.  @Bianca

Comment: how about wind from desk fan? @TonyStewart.EEsince'75

Comment: Aha. just don't think too much about today's youtube no-make-sense techie vids. I did with those kind of motor (taken from TAMIYA) on my fifth grade  elementary school. It did turns on a LED, but not that bright. Later on, i use motor from bicycle generator, the one that stick to the tire. It is working. The blade size 80 cm.

Comment: but i want output that is suitable for electronic devices. Does the motor produce DC output? I'm still confused. @Bianca

Comment: yes motors work as generators with V proportional to RPM but I proportional to torque load so coupling of fan wind energy is difficult without inertia of air such as an open field or roof top or very high speed or very large blades as you know from a paper windmill= with close proximity. A large 2 litre pop bottle is sometimes used as a turbine but the torque is weak without sufficient wind.  Wind has poor coupling properties unless you have high wing tip speed . This coupling factor we can model as a high resistance which is difficult to generate useful power is non-linear with wind speed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. Another thing, if I wanna get output 5V, Do i need 5V motor? or more than 5V motor? @TonyStewart.EEsince'75

Comment: low magnet stiction is essential. Remember to convert linear speed to RPM.   Put two fans together and see if one can drive the other. If the speed ratio is 1% the voltage best case with NO load is 1%.  YOu need to understand the coupling loss ...better

Comment: Check out this Q&A for a run-through of the basics. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177513/which-of-the-following-motors-best-suit-as-a-wind-generator. If you're using brushed DC motor it'll be less efficient btu you won't need a rectifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of a fan will give minimal power without very tight aerodynamic coupling. Direct access to the fan's power source would be far more efficient.

Various small WT (wind turbines) are available commercially that claim to be able to charge a battery pack and power electronic portable devices. All I have ever seen are junk.

Available power from an air stream is
Power = 0.6 x A x V^3 x K Watts
V = air velocity in m/s
A = cross section area of WT rotor in m^2
0 <= K <= 1 = efficiency.
K = :
0.4+ is available in large (MW level) well designed commercial WTs.
Magic needed.

0.2 - 0.3 DIY ascended masters and savy commercial startups.
Magic helps.

0.15 - 0.2 achievable with very well designed and built DIY devices. Not at all easy.

~= 0.1 - creditable achievement for small DIY units.

Assume k=0.1
From above - Power = 0.6 x A x V^3 x K Watts

At 1 m/s air velocity you get 60 mW per square meter.
At 2 m/s you get 480 mW / m^2- the cubed term in V helps
At 3 m/s you get 16 W/m^2.

A 100mm dia rotor has an area of 0.00785 m^2. Wow.
At (even) 3 m/s you get 16 x 0.00785 = 125 mW.

To charge an eg cellphone at 5V. 1A you need 5 Watts.
A 700mm dia WT rotor has area = 0.385 m^2.
Power at 3 m/s with K=0.1 = 6.2 Watts - about right for a 5W cellphone charger. About right to charge a 1400 mAh battery (iPhone etc).

3 m/s =~ 11 km/hour "breeze".

A 700mm dia = 2'-4" dia WT in a 3 m/s wind (across whole disk) is about entry level for your requirement using the above assumptions.

**________________________**

Typical pretty looking garbage:

[image]

[From here](http://thefutureofthings.com/5965-hymini-hybrid-mini-green-power-bank/)

Think about these specs - rotor size, power out and needed wind speed.
The claimed spec amounts to an achieved K of about 0.15 (at about 15 kph wind speed).

- HYmini is a handheld hybrid mini ‘green’ power station. Measuring only 5.4 inches (134mm) X 3.4 inches (87.5mm), it uses three power sources: renewable wind power, solar power, and the conventional electric power outlet. The energy collected by the HYmini is stored in its internal battery, providing the user with a compact, portable device that can be used to recharge cell phones, MP3 players, iPods, PDAs, digital cameras or other 5V devices.

  HYmini can harness wind power via its built-in micro wind power generator –  a supplemental power source with a 65 mA capacity. It requires a minimum 9mph wind speed in order to start recharging.

Comment: The type of voltage output generated from wind turbine is AC voltage or DC voltage? I'm a bit confused. Does it depend on type of motor we use?

Comment: @AmmarMahadi Brushed DC motors make DC. AC motors with permanent magnet rotors make AC. Brushless DC motors make AC but you need yo bypass the control electronics if fitted.